# Is there an established mathematical term for "vector rejection"?

Tags: математика

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula#Derivation):

> Using the dot and cross products, the vector v can be decomposed into components parallel and perpendicular to the axis k, where the component parallel to k is called the *vector projection* of v on k, and the component perpendicular to k is called the *vector rejection* of v from k.

"Vector projection" is *проекция вектора v на k* in Russian, but I've never heard the term "vector rejection" before — in English or in Russian.

Is there an established Russian term for it?

Comment: Я б сказал проекция к нормали k и честно говоря ничего другого в данном контексте не слышал.

Comment: I reject the idea of using “rejection” like that in math in English.  Please do not try to create a Russian analogue of that ridiculous terminology. Follow the suggestion of shabunc.

Comment: I have never heard vector rejection used in mathematics.

Comment: @shabunc isn't it проекция на нормаль к оси k?

Comment: @il--ya yeah, it definitely might be, may be my memory does not serve me well

Answer (score 1):

If you need a term, you can say *ортогональная **составляющая** вектора v относительно оси k* (as opposed to *ортогональная **проекция** вектора v на ось k*). Bear in mind, though, that this is not a term from vector algebra, which seems to be the context of your question; this is a term from abstract algebra.

Other than that, the best way to describe this concept would be *проекция вектора v на плоскость, перпендикулярную оси k*.

Answer (score -1):

It can be translated as "вертикальная компонента вектора v", but only in the context of projection.